# Do I need a transit visa in Dublin?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, dub

I'm an Indian citizen, holding a valid Canadian visitor's visa. I'm traveling from Canada through Dublin to another destination. Does Dublin require a transit visa?

Comment: What is your itinerary? Do you have a stop in the UK? What other visas do you have?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not planning to leave the airport you will not need a transit visa. [Citizens of India do not need transit visas in Ireland](http://inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Transit%20Visas).